# Git revert 2 commits with one being merge

Tags: git

I am trying to revert back 2 commits back, first is a merge commit and second a normal commit.

Problem I am facing is normal `git revert` without using `-m` doesn't work for merge commits. And where I get the option, it considers only the last merge commit but I want to revert back 2 commits.

So, this is the current structure :

```
commit HASH_ONE(HEAD -> Release_Stage, origin/Release_Stage)
Merge: merge_hash_one merge_hash_two
Author: 
Date:   

    resolving merge conflict Branch_name

commit HASH_TWO(origin/PSP-8392, PSP-8392)
Author: 
Date:   

    adding comment during kyc upload

commit HASH_THREE (origin/Release, origin/PSP-8594, Release)
Merge: merge_hash_one merge_hash_two
Author: 
Date:   

    Merged in PSP-6887_new (pull request #411)

    some commit message
```

So, here I want to get back to HASH_THREE using `git revert` only as I can't do force push.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is create a new revision on top of HASH_ONE that will make the content of the project be like it is in HASH_THREE, it can be easily done like this:

```
git checkout HASH_THREE # assuming that it is a revision ID... if it is a branch, use --detach so that it doesn't move
git reset --soft HASH_ONE
# all changes between HASH_ONE an HASH_THREE (moving backwards) will be in index ready to be committed
git commit -m "reverting to HASH_THREE"
# now you have a single revision on top of HASH_ONE that is taking you back to the content of HASH_THREE
# feel free to put a branch here and then check it out
git branch -f some-branch
git checkout some-branch
```

Another rather simple approach is using the not-to-be-used-everyday commands:

```
git branch -f temp $( git commit-tree -p HEAD -m "Reverting to HASH_THREE" HASH_THREE^{tree} )
```

That will create a temp branch on a new revision that has your current branch as its parents and the content of the revision is the same as `HASH_THREE`. You can then merge that branch so that your branch moves there:

```
git merge temp
```

Feel free to delete `temp` branch after you are done.

Comment: I have to be in the same branch. And in the same branch I cannot force push.

Comment: That's not a problem.... you won't rewrite history. Just use that branch on the last 2 commands because you will be working on detached HEAD

Comment: I am already in the current branch so, why the last 2 commands?

Comment: Because the first command (the checkout) should get you into `detached HEAD` and so the one commit you will create will be associated to no branch. So the last 2 commands will set whatever branch you want at that revision (it can be the branch you are working on).

Comment: So, for 2 commit revert similar to `git reset --soft HASH_ONE` I will also do reset for HASH_TWO right?

Comment: The thing is that git is actually not _caring_ for the revisions in between. Let me add another way to do it, just as an example.